# How to Generate unique random number?

Tags: mysql

Can someone tell me a good method for automatically placing a unique random number in a mysql database table when a new record is created.

Comment: timestamp not good enough?

Comment: @NanheKumar Congratulations. You just linked to **this page**.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a table with a pool of numbers:

```
Create Table pool (number int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT);
Insert Into pool (),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),…;
```

And then define a trigger which picks one random number from that pool:

```
CREATE TRIGGER pickrand BEFORE INSERT ON mytable 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE nr int;
  SET nr = (SELECT number FROM pool order by rand() limit 1);
  DELETE FROM pool WHERE number = nr;
  SET NEW.nr = nr;
END
```

In order to avoid concurrency issues you have to run queries in transactions. If performance becomes an issue (because of the slow `order by rand()`) you can [change the way to select a random record](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4329447/1346207).

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is `Autoincrement` Column

[see here for syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

perhaps for Random number 
try this!

```
select FLOOR(RAND() * 401) + 100
```

**edit**

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 99999) AS sup_rand
FROM table
WHERE "sup_rand" NOT IN (SELECT sup_rand FROM table)
LIMIT 1
```

Steps:

```
1.Generate a random number
2.Check if its already present
3.if not continue use the number
4.Repeat
```

Comment: He said random, not serial

Answer (score 0):

Your criteria of *unique* and *random* are generally conflicting. You can easily accomplish one or the other, but both is difficult, and would require evaluating every row when testing a new potential number to insert.

The best method that meets your criteria is to generate a UUID with the [`UUID` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid).

The better choice would be to re-evaluate your design and remove one of the (unique, random) criteria.

Comment: `UUID` function will not return number? and random string in quite big

Comment: Because it is difficult to efficiently generate a unique random number. You haven't specified how big you want it to be. What happens when there are that many results?